# Why can't I delete this remote bookmark in Mercurial (hg)?

Tags: mercurial

**EDIT:** Mercurial version is 2.7

**EDIT2:** I have divergent bookmarks here, but want to delete one of them instead of merging them.

I read that I could delete a remote bookmark `foo` using

```
hg book -d foo
hg push -B foo
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, while trying to delete the bookmark `@default` locally (which works) and then remotely (which doesn't work, so it gets restored again on next pull):

```
$ hg pull
pulling from /tmp/foo/base
searching for changes
no changes found
divergent bookmark @ stored as @default

$ hg book
* @                         8:d7a82de9f7c9
  @default                  9:c12daad73af2

$ hg book -d @default

$ hg book
* @                         8:d7a82de9f7c9

$ hg push -B @default
pushing to /tmp/foo/base
searching for changes
no changes found
bookmark @default does not exist on the local or remote repository!

$ hg in -B
comparing with /tmp/foo/base
searching for changed bookmarks
no changed bookmarks found

$ hg out -B
comparing with /tmp/foo/base
searching for changed bookmarks
no changed bookmarks found

$ hg pull
pulling from /tmp/foo/base
searching for changes
no changes found
divergent bookmark @ stored as @default

$ hg book
* @                         8:d7a82de9f7c9
  @default                  9:c12daad73af2
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you run `hg bookmarks`? What version of hg?

Comment: I added the version of hg (2.7). The output of hg book(marks) is already shown above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the remote bookmark is `@`, not `@default`.  All you need to do is delete `@default` locally, then push `@` back to the remote repository.  That will update the remote repository to agree with your `@` bookmark.

#### Example (Windows batch file):

```
hg init a
cd a
echo >file1
hg ci -Am1
hg clone . ..\b
echo >file2
hg ci -Am2
hg book @
hg log
@REM *** At this point "a" has a bookmark on the changeset with comment "2"
cd ..\b
echo >file3
hg ci -Am3
hg book @
@REM *** At this point "b" has a bookmark on the changeset with comment "3"
hg pull ..\a
@REM *** Mercurial 2.7 named the divergent bookmark @1.
@REM *** I delete the local divergent bookmark and push back to "a" (including new changeset)
hg boo -d @1
hg push ..\a -f -B @

@REM *** Display "b" log
hg log

@REM *** Display "a" log...bookmark is moved to changeset with comment "3"
cd ..\a
hg log
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution is to simply push the original bookmark rather than the deleted one.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a case of [Divergent Bookmarks](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/bookmarks/#divergent-bookmarks)!

I believe (though note that I've not attempted yet to recreate this on a remote repo to test) that the remote repo believes that it has an update to a bookmark that your local repo has also updated. The name isn't rendered though, which is weird; is it named with whitespace, something the CLI can't render, or maybe the '@' symbol itself? You may just have a corrupt entry in the remote repo's bookmarks file.

When you pull a bookmark and both local and remote have updated the same bookmark, that creates a divergent bookmark. The remote version is appended with "@[path]" where path is pulled from the [paths] section of the hgrc file based on the source of the remote repo. (See `hg paths` for more on that.) The "@[path]" version only exists locally until you merge and delete the divergent bookmark.

I *think* that if you were to merge and push to the remote repo, you'd resolve the bookmark issue and things would be back to normal.

---

In your comment you said that you were intentionally using a bookmark named "@", referencing the help for bookmark: "If you set a bookmark called '@', new clones of the repository will have that revision checked out (and the bookmark made active) by default."

In this case, to prevent the creation of the `@default`, you need to have the two repos agree on which changeset should have the `@`; basically you need to fix the divergent. Given that you don't want to merge and push back to the remote repo, that means updating the `@` bookmark to match the remote repo.

With the example console in your question, I believe that deleting the divergent bookmark and resetting the `@` bookmark to match the remote repo will prevent the divergent issue going forward:

```
hg book -d @default
hg book @ -r 9 -f
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I'm already aware that I have divergent bookmarks here. The issue is that I don't want to merge at this point but rather delete the @default bookmark. (The name of the original bookmark is really '@': "If you set a bookmark called '@', new clones of the repository will have
    that revision checked out (and the bookmark made active) by default." - from `hg help book`)

Comment: Hey Kevin! I understand your question better after your comment. Does the addition to my answer help?

Comment: Thanks for your Edit! While this fixes things in the local repository, it doesn't fix the divergent bookmark on the remote side. Pushing the original bookmark @ after deletion of @default works, as posted by Mark.